# ElasticSearch I can't find IndexParameters

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

It appears that the IndexParameters class does not exist anymore in nest 5.0 and I cannot find any reference to which class I should use in its place.
We were using nest version 0.11.1 and we need to do move the project on next 5.0.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**
I have an interface that declare a method like this:

```
Index<T>(T @object, IndexParameters indexParameters) where T : class
```

The later the interface is implemented and in the implementation I've got only this:

```
return _elasticClient.Index(@object, indexParameters);
```

I can't find any information about IndexParameters in nest 5.0.

Comment: May you share code you are trying move to 5.x?

Comment: @Rob I have added a code sample. hope it helps

Comment: `IndexParameters` doesn't exist in recent versions on NEST. You will find a lot of useful information in official NEST documentation, it's well written and full of code samples. [This](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/master/nest-getting-started.html#_indexing_2) will help you with indexing.